# left join not working

Tags: mysql, join

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL 
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
`value` INT(10) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO table1
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);

INSERT INTO table2
VALUES (1, 100), (2, 200);
```

I want to get table like:

```
id value
1  100
2  200
3  null
4  null
```

My query is

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.value
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
```

and I got:

```
1 100
2 200
```

How should I query the database to get what I want?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3accb/1

Comment: "left join" means "left outer join". So the query does exactly the same as the accepted answer. There is something wrong with your question. can you check your question again?

Comment: +1 for providing DDL and DML - if only all posters did the same. Re. the default being an OUTER JOIN anyway, to get the result you showed in the question you must have used something like SELECT t1.id, t2.value
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.value
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id;

+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |   100 |
|  2 |   200 |
|  3 |  NULL |
|  4 |  NULL |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: it worked for me, thx

Comment: @Naix, This query is exactly what you have in the question! How did "this worked" and the original failed?!

Answer (score 1):

hye i tried below query in mysql and SQL server databases its working fine, so please check once again. and tell me which database u tried.

SELECT t1.id, t2.value
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id

```
id   value  
--  --------
 1       100
 2       200
 3    (NULL)
 4    (NULL)
```

Thanks.

Comment: no, it cannot work because you use an inner join. Maybe you entered too much data into `table2`. `table2` should contain only two rows.

Comment: no, i did not entered to much data only two columns i inserted as u gave. that is not Inner join , it is left join , so i got correct answer.

Comment: sorry, you are right. "left join" means "left outer join". "left inner join" does not make nay sense.